# Replace text between each couple of delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

```
a = "animal: [cat.], animal:[dog.]"
print(a)

>>> animal: [cat.], animal:[dog.]
```

I would like to replace *each* part of the string between `[` and `.]` (included) with a given value (e.g. `frog`).

The expected output is:

```
animal: frog, animal: frog
```

I tried the following so far:

```
import re

b = re.sub(r'(\[\b).*(\b\.])','frog', a)
print(b)

>>> animal: frog
```

That it slightly different from the expected output.

I think this is due to the fact the code see the first `[` and the last `.]` as delimiters, consequently replacing with `frog` all the string between.

Instead, I would like the code to consider two pairs of delimiters: those containing the word `cat` and those containing the word `dog`.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `.*` in regular-expression is greedy. This means that it will search for the "longest match". Try replacing the regex with this: `r'(\[\b).*?(\b\.])'`.
`?` Means that `*` will be non-greedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `.*` to `.*?` as `.*` matches everything greedily and will consume parts you don't want to match. Also better to remove groups from your regex as you aren't using them as it makes the regex perform better.

So, you can use `\[\b.*?\b\.]` and replace it with `frog` or anything as you like.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pVRW6f/2/)**

Check your updated Python code,

```
import re

s = 'animal: [cat.], animal:[dog.]'

b = re.sub(r'\[\b.*?\b\.]','frog', s)
print(b)
```

Prints,

```
animal: frog, animal:frog
```

Comment: Maybe he needs `\b` say for to guarantee a letter/number/underscore after/before the `\[\]`

Comment: @sln: You could be right. Although OP hasn't stated anything about those word boundaries but we can preserve them in case OP really needs them. Updated my post.

Comment: It is as sin mentioned :) thank you Pushpesh, Gby